# How to show this entire table?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I already created a table in Oracle 11g named CAR. But whenever I execute the query

`SELECT * FROM CAR;`

it shows me the error

> "No rows Selected"

Moreover I tried to create the same table again but it didn't create the newer one.

Please help me, How to get my table back? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KgaE.png)

Comment: did you insert any records into the table?

Comment: Did you commit the transaction after inserting the records into the table?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question I can't see when or what you actually entered in your table. You have to enter information into your table first before you can query it.

For now if you want to display the structure of your table (just to see if it exists) try executing:

```
describe car;
```

Comment: can you add your insert query? I think when inserting it gave an error

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bulk insert of data to populate your table like this
(You can even use Excel to handle all the formatting and copy hundreds of records):

```
     INSERT ALL
     INTO CAR (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)VALUES(111,'BMW',180)
     INTO CAR (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)VALUES(122,'MASERATI',458)
     INTO CAR (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)VALUES(133,'LOTUS',635)
     SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
     COMMIT;
```